# How to call and declare object for a method call in iOS

Tags: ios, methods, call

Say have "normal" class in iOS, called A. I'd like to pass this as a parameter to class B, method "myMethod".

"A" is declared as a pointer:

```
A       *myA;
```

I'm unclear as to the syntax of call. Here's the method (I think this is probably correct:

```
- (void *) myMethod:(A *) myA
```

Should the call be

[b myMethod:myA]

or

[b myMethod:&myA]

Since myA is a pointer, it's seems it should be the second one, but somehow I'm thinking it's the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the first:

`[b myMethod:myA]`

I rarely dereference pointers in Objective-C as I used to do in C/C++.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still confused - the "&" extracts the address, which should be what the pointer declarations receives. Why doesn't this have to be done?

Comment: when you write a method like `-(void)method:(MyObject*)obj` it receives a variable of type `MyObject*`.  When you pass a parameter in to that method, you define it as `MyObject *myObj`.  So it's the same going in as it is coming out.  You might be getting confused over the fact that C++ has dot (.) and arrow (->) operators.  Objective-C doesn't have this distinction.

Comment: one last thing... if you were to pass in &myObj into the method, you are taking myObj (which is defined as `MyObject*` and taking its address, which is an address of an address.  So you are effectively passing in a `MyObject**`.